# setting up R in conda environment with jupiter notebook

Tags: python, r, conda

This is supposed to be simple given recent stage of anaconda should be quite compatible with R. I am following this tutorial,

https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/mixed_lm_example.html

However, at this 3rd line,

```
%R library(lme4)
```

I got this error:

```
RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-ce7ee867bca4> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic(u'R library(lme4)')

/home/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in magic(self, arg_s)
   2158         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2159         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2160         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2161 
   2162     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/home/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2079                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2080             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2081                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2082             return result
   2083 

<decorator-gen-157> in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)

/home/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    186     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    187     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 188         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    189 
    190         if callable(arg):

/home/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.pyc in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)
    693         finally:
    694             if self.device in ['png', 'svg']:
--> 695                 ro.r('dev.off()')
    696 
    697         if text_output:

/home/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.pyc in __call__(self, string)
    361     def __call__(self, string):
    362         p = _rparse(text=StrSexpVector((string,)))
--> 363         res = self.eval(p)
    364         return conversion.ri2py(res)
    365 

/home/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    176                 v = kwargs.pop(k)
    177                 kwargs[r_k] = v
--> 178         return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    179 
    180 pattern_link = re.compile(r'\\link\{(.+?)\}')

/home/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    104         for k, v in kwargs.items():
    105             new_kwargs[k] = conversion.py2ri(v)
--> 106         res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
    107         res = conversion.ri2ro(res)
    108         return res

RRuntimeError: Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)
```

Does anyone know how to properly set up R with conda environment and be able to use it mixed with python as that tutorial does? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lme4 isn't in the conda package so you need to install.

https://conda.io/docs/commands/build/conda-skeleton-cran.html

Try installing the package through cran:

```
./bin/conda skeleton cran lme4
```

And then run:

```
./bin/conda build r-lme4/
```

Comment: When running  `conda build r-lme4/`, I got the error Could not download https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-01-01/src/contrib/Archive/lme4/lme4_1.1-17.tar.gz Do you know why?

Comment: Unfortunately I am having issues running r kernel in jupyter on mac so I can't test these in jupyter. Maybe try conda install -c r r-lme4 and if that doesn't work try a direct install in R itself install.packages("lme4", /"home/user/ananconda3/lib/R/library"), then library(lme4).